# I want to remove '>>" sign for each tab in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse

'>>' blur signs comes for each tab. Though i reset the settings for eclipse java editor but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have `whitespace characters` enabled in your eclipse configuration.

Go in your Eclipse preferences to `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors`. Uncheck the checkbox named `Show whitespace characters`.

It will disable the option, thus hiding the `>>` character indicating a tab.